# Doubts on Marinelli Menu

Tags: routes, navigation

I'm trying to have submenus like the ones that can be seen on http://marinelli.netsons.org in Cameras menu item.

Could anyone point me on how can I achieve that? I don't know how to create the sections that can be seen in that submenu.

Answer (score 1):

[Megamenu](http://drupal.org/project/megamenu) might be of use.

> Mega menus are a type of menu drop-down, which seeks to overcome some of the usability drawbacks to traditional style drop-downs. Primarily, mega menus have two advantages:
>
> 1. The information architecture of your navigation is made clearer and is visible all at once
> 2. The amount of clicking, searching, and navigating is reduced